# win7: chkdisk log truncated -- where is the rest?

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk, event-log

i had chkdisk run before windows starts. Looking into the event log i only see part of the log that chkdisk produced:

```
...
c0 04 f0 79 53 12 80 fa c0 04 f0 79 53 12 80 fa  ...yS......yS...
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x1 of index $I30
in file 0x196ae is incorrect.
41 b0 04 48 8b cb c7 44 24 28 04 20 53 56 c7 44  A..H...D$(. SV.D
24 20 00 02 00 00 e8 85 e7 ff ff 44 8b f8 85 c0  $ .........D....
The
```

this is how it ends, so its not the full picture. Googleing around I found a few having the same problem but without an answer, e.g. here:

- https://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/293645-chkdsk-event-viewer-doesnt-display-full-log.html
- https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/66622-chkdsk-report-cut-off-mid-way.html

What I'm almost certain is that chkdisk is most likely writing to a normal text file that and that gets put (partially) into the event log. this is based on the fact that source is Wininit and not chkdisk and happens when windows booted after chkdisk completed.
Searching all files with a modification time in question (between shutdown and before windows start) yielded no result.

So can anyone help on this front?

Answer (score 5):

ok, just found it myself thru this post: https://superuser.com/a/817920/521813

Its located in

```
drive:\System Volume Information\Chkdsk
```

Also:

1. you must give yourself access to `System Volume Information` first.
2. the file format is UTF 16 LE which is not handled automatically in CMD

Comment: You don't have to mess with permissions. Although by default you can't even get a listing of `System Volume Information`, you can still `cd` to the `chkdsk` directory if you run CMD/PowerShell as admin.